# Модификация изображения в php

Tags: php, php5

Здравствуйте как можно получить вот такой результат с помощью php при загрузки изображение на сервер. Чтобы загружаемые изображения сохранились с одинаковыми размерами (thumb)
при этом не сжимались

[image: картинка]

Answer (score 2):

Используйте библиотеку Imagick, метод [Imagick::cropImage](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.cropimage.php). Он делает как раз то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function minimilize($savefile){

    $image=new Gmagick($savefile);

    $width=$image->getimagewidth();
    $height=$image->getimageheight();

    $standartWidth='';
    $standartHeight='';
    $x='';
    $y='';

    if($width>$height) {

        $standartWidth=1024;
        $standartHeight=756;

        $masWidth=1300;
        $masHeight=900;


        $kw=$width/$masWidth;

        $wx=$width/$kw;

        $image->setCompressionQuality(80);
        $image->profileimage('*',null);
        $image->resizeimage($wx, $wx, null, 1, true);


        $x = (($masWidth - $standartWidth) / 2);
        $y = 0;
    }

    if($width<$height) {

        $standartWidth=1024;
        $standartHeight=756;

        $koef=$width/1024;
        $wx=$height/$koef;

        $image->setCompressionQuality(80);
        $image->profileimage('*',null);
        $image->resizeimage($wx, $wx, null, 1, true);

        $x = 0;
        $y = $wx/7.75;

    }

    $image->cropimage($standartWidth, $standartHeight, $x,$y);
    $image->writeimage($savefile);
    $image->destroy();
}
```

[вот другое решение](https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/php_gd.txt.html)

[еще раз](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=graph&page=014)

[как установить GM](http://odware.livejournal.com/477.html)

Comment: Что за "волшебное" число 7.75?

Comment: Это я просто **подобрал** координату

Comment: Вы же понимаете что это плохо?))

Comment: А как тогда задать координату "y" от чего оталкиваться?

Comment: А зачем нужен этот коэффициент? Смещение по вертикали? Для центрирования?

Comment: Для смещения по вертикали.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70270/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-dpi).

Answer (score 0):

Делается на обычном php (да, да, это говнокод, функциональщина, но может хватит уже либы везде и всюду пихать? давайте сначала основы учить):

```
function resize($image, $out, $w_o = false, $h_o = false) {
    // Размеры выходного изображения
    $outWidth = 120;
    $outHeight = 120;

    if (($w_o < 0) || ($h_o < 0)) {
        echo "Некорректные входные параметры";
        return false;
    }
    list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($image); // Получаем размеры и тип изображения (число)
    $types = array("", "gif", "jpeg", "png"); // Массив с типами изображений
    $ext = $types[$type]; // Зная "числовой" тип изображения, узнаём название типа
    if ($ext) {
        $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext; // Получаем название функции, соответствующую типу, для создания изображения
        $img_i = $func($image); // Создаём дескриптор для работы с исходным изображением
    } else {
        echo 'Некорректное изображение'; // Выводим ошибку, если формат изображения недопустимый
        return false;
    }
    /* Если указать только 1 параметр, то второй подстроится пропорционально */
    if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o / ($w_i / $h_i);
    if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o / ($h_i / $w_i);
    /* Задаем смещение, центрируя изображение */
    $marge_right = abs($outWidth - $w_o)/2;
    $marge_bottom = abs($outHeight - $h_o)/2;
    $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($outWidth,$outHeight); // Создаём дескриптор для выходного изображения
    imagefill($img_o,0,0,imagecolorallocate($img_o, 255, 255, 255));
    imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img_i, $marge_right, $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i); // Переносим изображение из исходного в выходное, масштабируя его
    return imagejpeg($img_o,$out,100); // Сохраняем изображение в тот же файл, что и исходное, возвращая результат этой операции
}

$rootPath=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
// Код ниже лучше использовать в цикле
$path=$rootPath."/in/".$inImage; // Изображение донор
$realImage=$rootPath."/out/".$outImage; //Выходное изображение
if(!is_file($realImage)){
    if(is_file($path)){
        list($width,$height)=getimagesize($path);
        if($height>$width){
            resize($path,$realImage,false,110);
        }else{
            resize($path,$realImage,110);
        }
    }
}
```

Магические число 120 выносим за функцию, естественно, и передаем в качестве аргумента. Магическое число 110 - это высота изображения, которое будет вставлено по центру 120-пиксельной конечной картинки.

**P.S.** Признаюсь честно, пробовал только на квадратных миниатюрах, т.е. 120х120, а внутри уже вертикальные картинки по 110, либо по ширине, либо по высоте.

**P.S.S.** Поставили минус - отпишитесь за что.

Comment: В чем проблема использовать библиотеку Imagick и не писать свои велосипеды?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan в том, чтобы сначала научиться готовить хотя бы простые блюда, а не лезть в шефповара

Comment: Он же не пишет библиотеку, а использует её.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan ТС пока ничего не использует, ему предложили всего лишь